# Test in-app purchase on iPhone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have an app on the market with in-app purchasing. I have had the worst time testing it since I have tested it with a sandbox account, and once the item is 'purchased' with the sandbox account, I can't repurchase the item for testing. I delete the app in between tests to clear the user data, but of course when I do a test purchase, it detects I've already purchased the item on my test account. This is causing problems because some of my users are having issues when purchasing the app for the first time - issues that I can't replicate on my sandbox account.

Is there a way to completely clear the past history of purchases on the sandbox account?

Comment: I always create a new sandbox account for this. Haven't figured out a way to 'clean' a sandbox account

Comment: But you need a different email address every time, right?

Comment: Are you sure that this is important thing to test? Your app shouldn't be able to tell the difference between a purchase of a non-consumable and a repurchase? What are you doing this test to validate?

Comment: Do you mean purchasing the in app purchase for the first time or purchasing the app itself?  Test accounts won't aid in purchasing the app.

Comment: test the in-app purchase the first time

Comment: See my answer below.  The messages received by your transaction observer are the same regardless of the purchase history of a user account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to worry about this, you can use the same user every time.

The workflow is the same; `StoreKit` will send the same messages to the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` regardless of the purchase history for a user so you can test your code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create new ITunes Connect Test User every time. Once you use a new account you will be able to replicate your issues.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with out creating a new account under a new e-mail address each time?

Comment: Unfortunately not any more.  A valid email address is required for each test user account.

Comment: Some (free?) email providers will ignore a - or + suffix in the user name in your email address, so you can make up an infinite number of email addresses using just one account.